# How to get different language text by GetWindowText?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

How to get different language text by GetWindowText? 
I have modfying a whiteboard project. When the user type in the whiteboard, the onchange function will called and will show the text in the whiteboard. However, when I type Japanese text (Non system default language) it shows "?" instead. The following is the code spinet for onchange.

```
void CHBEdit::OnChange() 
{
    static bool bChanged = true;
    CDC *pDC = GetDC();

    if (bChanged) {
        CString str;
        GetWindowText(str);
        m_strText = str;

        int iStartChar, iEndChar;
        GetSel(iStartChar, iEndChar);

        CRect rect;
        GetWindowRect(&rect);

        CFont *Oldfont = (CFont *)pDC->SelectObject(&m_Font);
        CSize size = pDC->GetOutputTextExtent(str); //+ "a");
        pDC->SelectObject(Oldfont);

        SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, size.cx, size.cy, SWP_NOMOVE);

        bChanged = false;
        SetWindowText(str);

        SetSel(iStartChar, iEndChar);
    }
    else        
        bChanged = true;

    ReleaseDC(pDC); 
}
```

I am really new in C++. I did research and had tried GetwindowTextW with UTF8 unicode, but it still showing "?". Maybe the logic wrong.

I would appreciate it if anyone could give me the solution to show different language text in the whiteboard. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`GetWindowTextW` is the right way. Windows uses UTF16 Unicode standard, with `wchar_t` wide string. UTF8 standard is commonly used with Linux and internet. You may need UTF16/UTF8 conversion only when exporting/importing data to other systems.

If you create a new MFC project it will be setup in Unicode and MFC functions will default to Unicode. Example:

```
//UNICODE project:
CString str;
GetWindowText(str);
MessageBox(str);
```

If project is Unicode, this will will work in Japanese and all other languages.

If you are working with a legacy MFC project which is stuck in in ANSI mode and you can't change it, use the following fix:

```
//ANSI project:
CStringW str;
GetWindowTextW(str);
MessageBoxW(str);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The project was multi-byte character set and can't change to use GetWindowTextW.
Then I converted the whole project with the use unicode character set instead of multi-byte character set.
However, this method made a lot of variables need to change its' type.

Comment: I don't know how this is implemented in VS 2005, but in modern versions you should not care about `GetWindowTextW `/`GetWindowTextA`, as `GetWindowText` is implemented as a macro that automatically resolves to  one of those two functions, depending if the project is defined as being Unicode or not. I work also with projects supporting Japanese language using extensively `GetWindowText` and I do not have the problems you are complaining about!